# Sitecore 8 MVC AB Testing via experience editor - Save exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, ab-testing, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to create some AB Test via experience editor in sitecore 8 MVC,
After create a test component button in experience editor I can create a some test variation,and it is working well in editor,
If I click save button I see next error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: args.Item

Description: An unhandled exception occurred. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: args.Item

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <div class="wide">
Line 2:      <div class="container">
Line 3:      @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main-content")
Line 4:      </div>
Line 5:  </div>

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Views\HomePage.cshtml    Line: 3 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: args.Item]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +63
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetOptimizationRenderingChromeData.Process(GetChromeDataArgs args) +70
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +331
   Sitecore.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetChromeDataPipeline.Run(GetChromeDataArgs args) +264
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.RenderingMarker.GetClientData() +197
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.RenderingMarker.get_ClientData() +31
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.RenderingMarker.GetStart() +19
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.Wrapper..ctor(TextWriter writer, IMarker marker) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.AddWrapper.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +331
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +165
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +216
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +331
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +165
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
   ASP._Page_Views_PageContainers_HomePage_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Views\HomePage.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +157
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +176
```

What can i do with it ?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, it worked fine after republish the site.

i hop it will work for you.